# Is there any way to change priority of rendering components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a heavy component (ComponentOne) which needs several second to computation and I want to render ComponentOne after ComponentTwo without changing their places.

```
function HOME(){

  //some code

  return(
         <>
           < ComponentOne />
           < ComponentTwo />
         </>  )
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of computation.
Did you try to do that inside a `useEffect` hook in `ComponentOne` and put the result in a `useState` state?
But either way, the computation will probably make the UI unresponsive and might even lead to an error for the user.
It could be worth investing in a web worker.

Comment: yeah it worked hardly , I think its better to do this with web workers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easistes way is to use a state to managed mounted state of the second component (mounted) and then render the first so

```
const ComponentTwo  = ({onMount}) => {
    React.useEffect(()=>{
          onMount()
    },[])
   
    return (
          ...
    )
}

const FatherComponent = () => {

    const [secondElementRenedered, setSecondElementRenedered] = React.useState(false)
    
    return (
        <>
            {secondElementRenedered && (< ComponentOne />)}
            <ComponentTwo onMount={()=>setSecondElementRenedered(true)} />
        </>
    )
}
```

But remember:

if it is possible you can move computation data outside the rendering and maybe inside a worker. this should be a much better solution because the rendering function will make the entire page to hang until the rendering process is complete.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: it worked ,thank you , and yeah maybe the best way for this situation is using web workers.